# Application DbContext does not implement interface member error AS.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I realise this question had been asked before. However I tried the previous solutions and none of them worked for me. I am trying to isolate the real DB in order to run the mocking dependency test by using a fake DB context. I create an `ApplicationBbContext` for this reason, but having difficulties to figure out why do get an error with Application DbContext does not implement interface member error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using MVC_ATM.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MVC_ATM.ViewModels;
using MVC_ATM.Migrations;

namespace MVC_ATM.ViewModels
{
    public interface IApplicationDbContext
    {
        IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkingAccounts { get; set; }
        IDbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        int SaveChanges();
    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext //This is the first error
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
        public IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkAccounuts { get; set; }

        public IDbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}
//This IApplication db is made for mock testing 
public class FakeApplicationDBContext : IApplicationDbContext //This is the second error 
{
    public IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkAccounuts { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Transactions controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVC_ATM.ViewModels;
using MVC_ATM.Models;

namespace MVC_ATM.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AllTransactionsController : Controller
    {
        private IApplicationDbContext DB;

        public AllTransactionsController()
        {
            DB = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public AllTransactionsController(IApplicationDbContext DBContext)
        {
            DB = DBContext;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the inherited interface declares

```
IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkingAccounts { get; set; }
```

and in the implementations they have

```
 public IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkAccounuts { get; set; }
```

`checkAccounuts` instead of `checkingAccounts` which does not match the contract defined by the interface. Thus the compile time error.